# XSLT to copy value in a node to another across repeating nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

very new to XSLT and needs some help in transforming the XML. The below XML can have multiple "row" tags

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:row>
        <ns1:City>BALTIMORE</ns1:City>
        <ns1:Miscdata>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>123</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>2</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>345</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>8</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
        </ns1:Miscdata>
</ns1:row>

    <ns1:row>
            <ns1:City>FREMONT</ns1:City>
            <ns1:Miscdata>
                <ns1:Building>
                    <ns1:VendorCode>332</ns1:VendorCode>
                    <ns1:Value>4</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Building>
                <ns1:Building>
                    <ns1:VendorCode>342</ns1:VendorCode>
                    <ns1:Value>14</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Building>
                <ns1:Building>
                    <ns1:VendorCode>323</ns1:VendorCode>
                    <ns1:Value>233</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Building>
            </ns1:Miscdata>
    </ns1:row>
```

The value in "VendorCode" tag in the above XML needs to be copied to "Value" tag. The output XML would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:row>
        <ns1:City>BALTIMORE</ns1:City>
        <ns1:Miscdata>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>123</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>123</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>345</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>345</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
        </ns1:Miscdata>
</ns1:row>
<ns1:row>
        <ns1:City>FREMONT</ns1:City>
        <ns1:Miscdata>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>332</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>332</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>342</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>342</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
            <ns1:Building>
                <ns1:VendorCode>323</ns1:VendorCode>
                <ns1:Value>323</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Building>
        </ns1:Miscdata>
</ns1:row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All such tasks use the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

as a starting point, then you add template for the nodes that need special treatment e.g. in your case

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Building/ns1:Value">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ns1:VendorCode"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```